# In what ways is 'dilettante' offensive -- does it imply pretence?

Tags: meaning

Wikipedia on dilettante lists

> - An amateur, someone with a casual or superficial interest
> - A layperson,
>     someone without formal qualifications within a specific field

And some rock bands. Wikitionary lists two senses of the word

> - An amateur, someone who dabbles in a field out of casual interest    rather than as a profession or serious interest.
> - (sometimes offensive) A person with a general but superficial    interest in any art or a branch of knowledge.

I'm interested in how that term can be used offensively: is it a statement of pretence, or merely ignorance? If the former, then what sort of pretence is that?

Comment: i think i got the sense now -- if you're a "dilettante" then the "pretence" is that you are in some significant sense different from those that are unintersted in art. hmm

Comment: It can be a put-down in the same way that *amateur* can be a put-down. In particular, it can be used by some experts or professionals to put down non-experts or non-professionals, i.e., to distinguish themselves as superior in their area of expertise.

Comment: @Drew good comment, thanks, i think i may have seen it used in this elitist context

Comment: To figure out the meaning, sometimes it helps to try to figure out the motivation, and in that endeavor it sometimes helps to follow the money -
 examine the status/privilege/position of the speaker.

Comment: It's probably got the stronger negative value because it is a french word, and requires a broader vocabulary to use it ...both of which more elitist people are fond of using ... perhaps even playfully self parodying as they do so, to dismiss the less knowledgeable.

Comment: The dilettante's motivation is perhaps the key to answering your question. Is the dilettante interested merely in impressing others or becoming accepted within a group of art lovers, even though he or she lacks the expert knowledge, training, and discriminating taste of the true connoisseur? (You know, "Look at me, see how tasteful I am. I own a de Kooning!") Moreover, the dilettante's interest in his or her "art du jour" wanes very quickly when he is not the center of attention or is "outed"  as a poseur. Then he will simply flit to another flower, partake of its nectar, and move on.

Answer (score 1):

The Italian present participle of *dilettare* with the agent sense “one who delights” was adopted into English to designate those who delight in contemplating a particular art (or the arts generally), as opposed to those who practice the art.

But professional artists and professional students of the arts—indeed, professionals in any field—are often annoyed by the superficial and uninformed judgments of outsiders who do not engage with their subject at a deep level of understanding; so among professionals the term *dilettante* quickly became a term of opprobrium, designating the sort of people who say “I don’t know much about art but I know what I like”

—or even worse, the sort of people who *think* they're experts, *think* they know what they're talking about, but are actually ignorant. That's where your *pretense* comes in, not so much in the sense of knowingly claiming an expertise you don't possess as in the sense of falsely believing you possess that expertise. Compare the [Dunning-Kruger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

Exactly the same thing happened with *amateur*, adopted via French from Latin *amator*, agent derivative of *amare*, “love”. Here are the *OED 1* definitions:

> **1.** A lover of the fine arts ; originally, one who cultivates them for the love of them rather than professionally, and so = *amateur* as opposed to *professional* ; but in later use generally applied more or less depreciatively to one who interests himself in an art or science merely as a  pastime and without serious aim or study (‘a mere dilettante’).
>     — [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/oed03arch#page/n377/mode/2up), *s.v.* **Dilettante**
>
> **1.** One who loves or is fond *of* ; one who has a taste for anything .
> [...]
> **2.** One who cultivates anything as a pastime, as distinguished from one who prosecutes it professionally ; hence, sometimes used disparagingly, as dabbler or superficial student or worker.
>     — [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/oed01arch#page/264/mode/2up), *s.v.* **Amateur**

Comment: hm so the offensiveness is cos of "ignorance" -- and the pretence is feigned knowledge. the answer is well presented, thanks, and got to point as well. you don't quite cover the concept i was referring to in my comment on the question -- of pretentiousness -- in referencing "i know what i like", unless the implicit claim is that this is meant snobbishly.

Comment: @user3293056 The 'feigned knowledge' is not necessarily deliberately feigned--dilettantes doesn't necessarily know that they're ignorant, they may merely think wrongly that what they 'know' is accurate or sufficient.

Comment: sufficient in the sense of "expertise", is what you seemed to say in your answer -- is that still all you mean? sorry for misreading the "not so much" claim -- as being ironic (not sure why i would do that). i wonder how to sidestep the put down, when to claim to know enough to not warrant further interest

Answer (score 1):

A dilettante is someone who may be a "lover" of a subject (as pointed out by other posters, the root word is the same as the one for "delight"), but lacks true expertise.

It doesn't necessary refer to "pretense" in a deceptive way, but it may be associated with someone who is considered a "pretender" rather than a "contender" in the field. That may or may not be pejorative.

Answer (score 0):

It implies pretence if the person to which it refers regards themself as a professional or expert.  I do not regard it as an inherently offensive word (I would happily accept the designation for myself), but it can be used to accuse someone of over-rating their own knowledge or skill.